# File Store for WordPress Plugin Data

Tags: wordpress, plugins, store

I have a WordPress plugin. It makes virtual tours from equirectangular images (https://www.flickr.com/groups/equirectangular/). Now I plan to make support mipmap levels for images (different resolutions depending on zoom), but I do not know where I should save this data. The user should select his panorama image from the media library, then the plugin should generate mipmap images. What is best place to store this images, I think the media lirary is not good place for this data, also as a database.

Comment: Why not just use the [flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) to fetch the data instead of saving it?

Comment: Flickr is just an example. As I said I developed the plugin and I do not know where my user save their photos, it's a media library most of case. I asked what is a good place for storing a plugin data (I use custom post type and database for settings, but for images???)

Comment: Got it. I think the convention is storing data in `wp-content/uploads` folder. Probably you can use that?